# Number of solutions to matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

It is desired to find w = Pu, which is the orthogonal projection of u onto the column space
of an m × n matrix V . For V given by the matrix below, which of the following is correct?

V is

[image: https://i.imgur.com/nvVa9CS.png]

I was thinking since the column space is rank 1 there would be only one possible solution regardless of u. Is this a correct line of thinking or not? The potential answers are 0 solutions, 1 solution, infinitely many possible, or depends on u.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrasing of this question is a bit odd, but this should help you:

The column space of $V$ is given by the span of its columns. You can probably see that the two columns are multiples of one another, and that the column space can be expressed as

$$t\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\1\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$ where $t$ may be any real (or complex) number.

This space is one-dimensional (as you pointed out in your original post), so you can picture it as a line. How many different ways to project a vector onto a line are there?